# How to configure copy command in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

i wants to know how to configure the executestream command for the below command.

```
copy C:\input\ip.txt \\host2\C:\destFolder\ip.txt
```

Actually if i open cmd prompt(AnyPath) then write this command it could worked in windows.

But i need to process those command in NiFi.

I tried those command in following attributes like below.

```
Command Arguments:copy C:\input\ip.txt \\host2\C:\destFolder\ip.txt
Command Path:C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
Argument Delimiter: space
```

Here after success of executestream command processed in OutputStream relationship but functionality of the command not issued.

In that command i have copy the file(ip.txt) from host1 into host2 machine.Generally if i run that command in cmd.exe then file copied into host2.

But if configure those parameters in ExecuteStreamcommand i have received outputstream but my command not run and file not moved into host2.

Can anyone guide me to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

you are trying to call a command without any streaming of the flow file.

so you need `ExecuteProcess` processor

Example with `dir` command:

```
Command   : cmd
Arguments : /C dir c:\11
Delimiter : [space]
```

`/C` for `cmd` means call and exit

Comment: on the windows this command lists files under the `c:\11` folder.

Answer (score -1):

Command Arguments:`copy C:\input\ip.txt \\host2\C:\destFolder\ip.txt`

Add to front [**/C**]
Command Arguments:`**/C** copy C:\input\ip.txt \\host2\C:\destFolder\ip.txt`